# When doing a sort in typescript I get a git bash compiler type error

Tags: typescript

When doing a sort in typescript I get a git bash error but code works fine

I'm using webpack angular version 4 with typescript in angular cli.

When doing an ng serve I get typescript arithmetic operator error.

The sort function has the issue below.
The sort code looks fine in terms of js but when in ts it doesnt compile.

**Here's my code that works but fails when compiling in typescript:**

```
getAllJobs = (): void => {
      this.recentJobs = [];
      let allJobs = [];
      this.jobService.getAllJobs().then((allJobs: any) => {

           //Error here - sort error here in typescript compiler
            allJobs.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
              return new Date(b.sortDate) - new Date(a.sortDate);
            });

      });
  }
```

Comment: `Date`s are objects, and while subtraction works on them in JavaScript, to TypeScript it looks like you're subtracting objects. Instead, try using `return (new Date(b.stortDate)).valueOf() = (new Date(a.stortDate)).valueOf();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript complains because it thinks that since `Date` is an object and you are using it with arithmetic operators, they are incompatible. But what actually happens in JavaScript when you do this is `(new Date(b.sortDate)).valueOf() - (new Date(a.sortDate)).valueOf();` where `new Date().valueOf()` returns a number.

You can use the `+` operator to coerce the date to a number and do a comparison:

```
allJobs.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
      return (+new Date(b.sortDate)) - (+new Date(a.sortDate));
});
```

Or use `new Date().valueOf()` which returns a number:

```
allJobs.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
      return (new Date(b.sortDate)).valueOf() - (new Date(a.sortDate)).valueOf();
});
```

Here's a similar issue on the TypeScript repository that might be of interest to you: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5710